# How can i have two snippets for PHP in VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

This is how I imagined that I could do it but I see that it is overwritten and only the last one is working:

```
{
    "php": {
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": [ "<?php $1 ?>" ],
        "description": "php tag",

        "prefix": "echo",
        "body": [ "echo \"$1\";" ],
        "description": "php tag"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not even valid JSON. You should be getting green squiggly lines that display *Duplicate object key* on hover:

[image: Duplicate object key]

You need to edit the `snippets\php.json` file and add several sub-objects to the top-level object identified by different key names; such key is meant to contain the snippet name, not the language, which is already set in the file name:

```
{
    "PHP tags": {
        "prefix": "php",
        "body": [ "<?php $1 ?>" ],
        "description": "php tag"
    },
    "echo statement": {
        "prefix": "echo",
        "body": [ "echo \"$1\";" ],
        "description": "php tag"
    }
}
```